# Using RAND() function from SQL with Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I've been stuck with this for about 10 hours

I need to use this query (an optimized version of ORDER BY RAND)

```
public function findAllRandom()
{
   return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE RAND() < 0.0001 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20')
    ->getResult();
}
```

And of course since I'm using DQL I need to implement the RAND() function

```
<?php
namespace Gabriel\UploadBundle\DoctrineFunctions;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

/**
 * RandFunction ::= "RAND" "(" ")"
 */
class Rand extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{ 
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'RAND()';
    }
}
```

//Config.yml

```
orm:
(...)
    dql:
       numeric_functions:
         Rand: Gabriel\UploadBundle\DoctrineFunctions\Rand
```

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

The source of the RAND() source code:

> https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/919465

How to add from the config:

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html

demo about adding functions to DQL

> http://punkave.com/window/2012/07/24/for-the-php-crowd-adding-custom-functions-to-doctrine-2-dql

EDIT:
After further research I found out that order by function isn't supported on dql:
source:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/faq.html#can-i-sort-by-a-function-for-example-order-by-rand-in-dql

To work around this the HIDDEN value can be added

```
public function findAllRandom()
{
   return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p,RAND() AS HIDDEN rand FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p ORDER BY rand')
    ->getResult();
}
```

but for some reason it doesn't work with the WHERE clause

```
public function findAllRandom()
{
   return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p,RAND() AS HIDDEN rand FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE rand < 0.00001 ORDER BY rand')
    ->getResult();
}
```

A solution for the where clause would be appreciated, everyone knows that using the ORDER BY RAND() function can slow down the server (in our case even crash it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a native SQL query from the controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Image WHERE RAND()<(SELECT ((10/COUNT(*))*10) FROM Image) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");

$statement->execute();
$images = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Benchmark results
http://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this implementation - https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Rand.php

Comment: sir, that's the exact same source code as mine.
(I even replaced my current code with that to recheck and got the exact same error)